# optimizing looping through rows and columns of an array

Tags: vba, excel

I have an array of about 400 columns and 30 rows
I want to go through all the columns and each row in every column, and test cell of each cell for something..like if it's holds a negative number, and if it does I want to copy the cell itself and certain cells above it to another sheet.

I have done this with 2 standard "`for-loop`", however it takes a lot of time and there are more than 10 different tests for each cell.

I was wondering if anyone knew a more efficient way of doing this, such as using "for each" statements...I've been trying this with no luck -

```
 Set FinalSht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Final")
    Cnter = FinalSht.Cells(5, FinalSht.Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
    Rowter = FinalSht.Cells(FinalSht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    Set AnRe = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Anomaly")
    AnRe.Cells.ClearContents

    Set SRng = FinalSht.Range(FinalSht.Cells(5, 3), FinalSht.Cells(14, Cnter))

    RowCount = 0
    ColCount = 0

    For Each RowRng In SRng.Rows
    RowCount = RowCount + 1

             For Each ColRng In SRng.Columns
             ColCount = ColCount + 1
             Select Case True
                Case FinalSht.Cells(RowRng.Rows, ColRng.Columns) < 0
                With AnRe
                     .Cells(RowCount, ColCount).Value = FinalSht.Cells(RowRng.Rows, ColRng.Columns).Value
                End With

                  End Select

                Next ColRng


 Next RowRng
```

thanks for any help I can get...

Comment: Your Cnetr variable seems to be wrong, shouldn't it go `xlToLeft`? Now you are checking 16000+ columns. That will speed thing up. Anyway, I'll get back to you with a code in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A few general things to check if your code is slow:**

Declare your variables to fit your data, see [here for more info](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic/Optimizing_Visual_Basic)

Get rid of unused variables, code parts

Check out [this](http://www.homeandlearn.org/for_each.html) for some ideas on how to use the `for each` loop (you don't need two for each loops to go through all cells in a range). `For each` is generally faster than `for` loops.

You really need to optimize your loops: make sure you only loop through what you really need to.

Also, optimize whatever is inside your loops. Make sure you are only doing whatever is necessary to do inside the loop, because that is what matters.

---

### About your code:

Basically your code was slow because of two things.

```
Cnter = FinalSht.Cells(5, FinalSht.Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
```

That `xlToRight` made it loop through 16000+ columns, instead of just 400. Big difference. All the rest I'm telling you is just 1% of the speed gain. When you are debugging a code, step through it with F8, and use watches or the locals window. [More info here.](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

The other problem was having two `for each` loops instead of just the one you actually need.

---

The below code took less than a second to run. Hope this helps.

```
Sub test()

Dim Finalsht As Worksheet
Dim AnEr As Worksheet
Dim Cnter As Integer
Dim Rownter As Long
Dim SRng As Range
Dim myCell As Range

  Set Finalsht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Final")
  Cnter = Finalsht.Cells(5, Finalsht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  Rowter = Finalsht.Cells(Finalsht.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

  Set AnRe = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Anomaly")
  AnRe.Cells.ClearContents

  Set SRng = Finalsht.Range(Finalsht.Cells(5, 3), Finalsht.Cells(14, Cnter))

  For Each myCell In SRng
    Select Case True
      Case myCell.Value < 0
        With AnRe
             .Cells(myCell.Row, myCell.Column).Value = myCell.Value
        End With

      End Select

  Next myCell

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot!
this works, however I want to copy specific cells...for example:                   if mycell.value < 0 then i want to copy the cell in the row that is 3 rows above that row.

Comment: well, then try `mycell.row-3`, or something like that. myCell in this code is a valid cell reference, like Activecell or range("a1"), you can just get its row number, and then use it.

Comment: Like this: `.Cells(myCell.Row, myCell.Column).Value = cells(myCell.row-3,mycell.column).Value` **OR** `.Cells(myCell.Row, myCell.Column).Value =myCell.Offset(-3,0).Value`

Comment: I'm sorry...can't get it to work. maybe I haven't explained it correctly.
if mycell.value < 0, then i want to copy the cell 3 rows up from this cell in the original sheet to the same place - 3 rows above the cell that contains the negative value in the new sheet. like copying the header above the cell with the negative value

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. I played with it, and the code does the trick...appreciate it

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Comment: You declare `Dim Rownter As Long` but assign to `Rowter`...and never use that variable. Tip: add `Option Explicit` to the very top of the module to get these declaration errors flagged.

Comment: That is true, thank you! I only left it there because OP didn't post the full Sub, and I assumed he needed it somewhere later. If not needed elsewhere, it should be deleted.